# How can I clean up data in Panda with series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have data which I need to remove weekend data, and weekdays of after hrs data, once it is done, I would like to use in plot, so it will not show gap btw cleaning up data. It should show completed continue to next time in plot.

How can I remove data with series?

```
datafield = data[['close', "open", "high", "low"]]
datafield ["hr"] = datafield .index.hour
datafield ["day"] = datafield .index.dayofweek
if datafield ["day"] < 4:
   if datafield ["hr"] > 19 and datafield ["hr"] < 15: 
                     #removing the off hrs data
                     print("cleaning up the data")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[~(df.index.dayofweek > 4 & pd.Series.between(df.index.hour, 15, 19))]
```

where `df` is your dataframe.

Comment: I got empty field when I do with it. 
```

Comment: when I tried with one condition, series = series [(backtest.day < 4)], it works, when I am combining data, it  is showing blank.

Comment: I think problem is btw 15 and 18. this works for 15 hrs. 
backtest = backtest[(backtest.day < 4) & (backtest.hr > 0) & (backtest.hr <= 15) ]

Comment: I see, it's probably because your condition. What range of time do you wanna exclude?

Comment: For example, as it's specified, it's not possible to select an hour greater than 19 that is also (`and`, `&`) fewer than 15... That's the reason for getting an empty series.

Comment: I want to exclude the timing 15 - 19 hrs.

Comment: `backtest = backtest[(backtest.day < 4) and ((backtest.hr <= 15) or (backtest.hr >= 18))]` i am trying with this, but condition is having error.

Comment: if i want to do other way around, i can do with             `backtest = backtest[~(backtest.index.dayofweek < 4 & pd.Series.between(backtest.index.hour, 19, 15))]` right?

Comment: If you want the other way around, just remove the `~` signal. It's not correct to specify a range starting with a bigger number than the range end. It would result in an empty dataframe, like before.